# Fantasy book set in multiple worlds: main character is looking for his brother in the Amazon

Tags: story-identification, books

I've been looking for this book for quite some time. It was in English. I remember reading it in high school, around 2005, and the copy I read looked old then, but the name of it is escaping me.

It's about a man in the British army if I'm remembering correctly, searching for his missing brother in the Amazon. He ends up traveling through several different worlds throughout the book. There are only sporadic details that I remember other than that, such as the main character being in a card game on the trip to the Amazon where the other players are cheating and one of the main character's companions having a revolver with a design on the grip.

The method for traveling through worlds was kind of vague. For example he simply passes out after passing through a specific point in the Amazon when the first move takes place.

The one character name I am able to remember is User Annie. She doesn't get introduced until late in the book.

Comment: When and where were you in high school? Was this in English? Do you remember anything about how this man is traveling between worlds? Is that something routine? Does he have an innate talent? A device?

Comment: It was published quite a while ago as the copy I read was quite old, this was in English and the method of him traveling between these worlds was always kind of vauge, for example he simply passes out after passing through a specific point in the amazon when the first move takes place.

Comment: :) Can you give an approximate date range for when you encountered it? Even if it were quite old, it can provide a detail for the range of possible dates.

Comment: It would've been about 2005 that I found it.

Comment: Passing through worlds via river is a strong element of the Otherland series, but otherwise plot doesn't match up, and it isn't that old.

Comment: @Radhil: I don't know if he means "the Amazon" as "the Amazon River" for "the Amazon Jungle".

Comment: I haven't read it myself, but this sounds a bit like what I've heard of [*Riverworld*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riverworld) (Farmer).

Comment: @SeanDuggan from what I can remember of the story there's parts where the main character is traveling on a river and a jungle.

Answer (score 5):

I did a search using Google Books for the term `User Annie`.  The book *The Black Tower* (1988) by Richard Lupoff came up (also known as *The Dungeon* Volume 1).  According to [a review on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/review/R28TYKGC3GYIMJ/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0553273469&nodeID=283155&store=books) it does contain the character User Annie.

> This is the first book in a series called “The Dungeon,” with each of the six books being written by a different author. It’s not a very promising start. The book is very slow. It has its moments but they are few and far between. **The one saving grace here is the rich and colorful characters, particularly Finnbogg and User Annie.**

It is about a man searching for his brother (according to [the Goodreads summary](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/16542.The_Black_Tower)) and traveling to different worlds along the way.

> The return of a classic "shared world" fantasy series created by Philip Jose Farmer, award-winning author of the Riverworld saga!
>
> Plunging into a vast prison that spans a planet, Clive Foliott faces a fantastic world of dwarves, cyborgs, and aliens unlike anything he has ever imagined. It is a multi-leveled collection of beings from the hidden folds of time and space. Trapped somewhere inside is Neville Foliott, Clive's twin brother, and no creature in the Dungeon will stop Clive from finding him...

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is the book I'm looking for, I've been trying to find a more in depth synopsis to confirm it but I haven't had any luck yet. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Dragonsl5 you can click the check mark next to this answer to mark it correct. This will reward Daphne B, who wrote it. It will also show other users that this is indeed the correct answer.